# In OpenMDAO, is there a way to ensure that the constraints are respected before proceeding with a computation?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, openmdao

I have a constrained nonlinear optimization problem, "A". Inside the computation is an `om.Group` which I'll call "B" that requires a nonlinear solve. Whether "B" finds a solution or crashes seems to depend on its initial conditions. So far I've found that some of the initial conditions given to "B" are inconsistent with the constraints on "A", and that this seems to be contributing to its propensity for crashing. The constraints on "A" can be computed before "B".

If the objective of "A" could be computed before "B" then I would put "A" in its own group and have it pass its known-good solution to "B". However, the objective of "A" can only be computed as a result of the converged solution of "B". Is there a way to tell OpenMDAO or the optimizer (right now I'm using ScipyOptimizerDriver and the SLSQP method) that when it chooses a new point in design-variable space, it should check that the constraints of "A" hold before proceeding to "B"?

A slightly simpler example (without the complication of an initial guess) might be:

There are two design variables `0 < x1 < 1`, `0 < x2 < 1`.
There is a constraint that `x2 >= x1`.

Minimize `f(sqrt(x2 - x1), x1)` where `f` crashes if given imaginary inputs. How can I make sure that the driver explores the design space without giving `f` a bad input?

Comment: Your question is very vauge and confusingly worded. It sounds like there are multiple issues at play, involving the computation of initial guesses, execution order, and respecting of constraints. Can you develop some kind of an example case to share here? At the very lease, we need a more clear diagram of the data flow (N2 perhaps)? A toy problem, would be best, even if it doesn't exhibit the instabilities; That way we could at least understand what you are trying to achieve more clearly

Comment: I'm not Jacob, but I will try to reword.

One of the earlier components in the model computes a constraint. He wants the model to stop execution if that constraint is violated, instead of running the entire model and /then/ checking the constraint violation.

Comment: I provided a simplified example. (In reality the design space and constraints are a bit more complicated. If the above were my problem then I would redefine the design variables so that the constraint could never be violated.)

Comment: Good NLP solvers will obey bounds before evaluating non-linear functions. So, in your example, I would create a linear constraint `y=x2-x1` with `y` a positive variable. With this, it is safe to evaluate `sqrt(y)`. Or may be `sqrt(y+0.00001)` so valid derivatives can be computed. (Note that SLSQP is a somewhat simplistic solver, so don't expect too much).

Answer (score 4):

I have two proposed solutions. The best one is highly problem dependent. You can either raise an `AnalysisError` or use numerical clipping.

```
import numpy as np

import openmdao.api as om

class SafeComponent(om.ExplicitComponent): 

    def setup(self): 
        self.add_input('x1')
        self.add_input('x2')

        self.add_output('y')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs): 

        x1 = inputs['x1']
        x2 = inputs['x2']

        diff = x1 - x2

        ######################################################
        # option 1: raise an error, which causes the
        #           optimizer line search to backtrack
        ######################################################
        # if (diff < 0): 
        #     raise om.AnalysisError('invalid inputs: x2 > x1')

        ######################################################
        # option 2: use numerical clipping
        ######################################################
        if (diff < 0): 
            diff = 0.

        outputs['y'] = np.sqrt(diff)

# build the model
prob = om.Problem()

prob.model.add_subsystem('sc', SafeComponent(), promotes=['*'])

prob.setup()

prob['x1'] = 10 
prob['x2'] = 20

prob.run_model()

print(prob['y'])
```

**Option 1: raise an `AnalysisError`**
Some optimizers are set up to handle this well. Others are not.
As of V3.7.0, the OpenMDAO wrappers for SLSQP from scipy and pyoptsparse, and the SNOPT/IPOPT wrappers from pyoptsparse all handle AnalysisErrors gracefully.

When the error is raised, the execution stops and the optimizer recognizes a failed case. It backtracks on the linesearch a bit to try and get out of the situation. It will usually try a few steps backwards, but at some point it will give up. So the success of this situation depends a bit on why you ended up in the bad part of the space and how much the gradients are pushing you back into it.

This solution works very well with fully analytic derivatives. The reason is that  (most) gradient based optimizers will only ever ask for function evaluations along a line search operation. So that means that, as long as a clean point is found, you're always able to be able to compute derivatives at that point as well.

If you're using finite-differences, you could end a line search right near the error condition, but not violating it (e.g. x1=1, x2=.9999999). Then during the FD step to compute derivatives, you might end up tripping the error condition and raising the error. The optimizer is not going to be able to recover from this condition. Errors during FD steps will effectively kill the whole opt.
So, for this reason I never recommend the `AnalysisError` approach if you're suing FD.

**Option 2: Numerical Clipping**

If you optimizer wrapper does not have the ability to handle an `AnalysisError`, you can try some numerical clipping instead. You can add a filter in your calcs to to keep the values numerically safe. However, you obviously need to use this very carefully. You should at least add an additional constraint that forces the optimizer to keep away from the error condition when converged (e.g. x1 >= x2).

One important note: if you provide analytic derivatives, include the clipping in them!

Sometimes the optimizer just wants to pass through this bad region on its way to the answer. In that case, the simple clipping I show here is probably fine. Other times it wants to ride the constraint (be sure you add that constraint!!!) and then you probably want a more smoothly varying type of clipping. In other words don't use a simple if-condition. Smooth the round corner a bit, and maybe make the value asymptotically approach 0 from a very small value. This way you have a c1 continuous function and the derivatives won't got to exactly 0 for these inputs.

Comment: In your answer you say that the AnalysisError option should work for the Scipy version of SLSQP, but in our testing that doesn’t seem to be the case. I can see in the OpenMDAO code that the other drivers have a try/except AnalysisError block, except for scipy_optimizer. Can you confirm that AnalysisError handling is or is not supported for ScipyOptimizer? We're using OpenMDAO 3.17.0

Comment: After reviewing the code, you're right. The scipy optimizer driver doesn't support this. SLSQP in pyoptsparse does. I've logged an issue to track the problem: https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/issues/2530